# Deleting Application Partition throws exception that object doesn't exist

Tags: c#, active-directory

Following [the guidance posted on MSDN as to how to create an application partition](http://msdn.com/library/windows/desktop/ms676320.aspx) I am running into an exception when deleting a partition that I just created.  The example below is being run against an AD LDS instance to which my user account has full admin rights. The funny thing is that it works the first time if the partition exists before the test fixture is used.

```
var connectionString = new Uri("LDAPS://localhost/DC=integrationtests,DC=contoso,DC=com");
var baseContainerName = connectionString.PathAndQuery.TrimStart('/');
var hostName = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().HostName;
var directoryContext = new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.DirectoryServer, hostName);
var configurationSet = ConfigurationSet.GetConfigurationSet(directoryContext);

var existingPartition =
                configurationSet.ApplicationPartitions.Cast<ApplicationPartition>().FirstOrDefault(
                    partition => baseContainerName.Equals(partition.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
if (existingPartition != null)
{
    existingPartition.Delete();
}

// DirectoryEntry requires that the scheme is uppercase (LDAP not ldap)
var authenticationOptions = AuthenticationTypes.FastBind | AuthenticationTypes.Delegation | AuthenticationTypes.Secure;
var ldapConnectionString = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "LDAP://{0}", hostName);
if (connectionString.Scheme.Equals("LDAPS", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    authenticationOptions = authenticationOptions | AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer;
    ldapConnectionString = ldapConnectionString + ":" + (connectionString.Port <= 0 ? "636" : connectionString.Port.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
using (var parent = new DirectoryEntry(ldapConnectionString, null, null, authenticationOptions))
{
    var partition = parent.Children.Add(baseContainerName, "domainDns");
    partition.Properties["instanceType"].Value = 5;
    partition.Properties["description"].Value = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;
    partition.CommitChanges();
}

var existingPartition2 =
                configurationSet.ApplicationPartitions.Cast<ApplicationPartition>().FirstOrDefault(
                    partition => baseContainerName.Equals(partition.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
if (existingPartition2 != null)
{
    // Throws here
    existingPartition2.Delete();
}
```

The call to existingPartition2.Delete() throws:

```
System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.ActiveDirectoryOperationException was unhandled
HResult=-2146233088
Message=There is no such object on the server.

Source=System.DirectoryServices
ErrorCode=-2147016656
StackTrace:
        at System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.ApplicationPartition.Delete()
        at LdapTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in d:\Projects\LdapTest\LdapTest\Program.cs:line 58
        at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
        at System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
        at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
        at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
        at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
        at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
        at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
        at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
        at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
InnerException: System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException
        HResult=-2147016656
        Message=There is no such object on the server.

        Source=System.DirectoryServices
        ErrorCode=-2147016656
        ExtendedError=8333
        ExtendedErrorMessage=0000208D: NameErr: DSID-03100213, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
    'CN=Partitions,CN=Configuration,CN={CB88D356-F030-4598-BD59-F810587A2C72}'

        StackTrace:
            at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntries.Remove(DirectoryEntry entry)
            at System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.ApplicationPartition.Delete()
```

Any thoughts as to what might be causing the second to throw?  I can see the crossRef object in place using ADSIEdit just before the call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working through the issue with Microsoft (PSS Case #112072417632086) it turns out that the ConfigurationSet class maintains a cache and needs to be refreshed if you have made changes.  Not very obvious, I know... Before the second partition existence check call refresh it by:

```
configurationSet = ConfigurationSet.GetConfigurationSet(directoryContext.Value);
```